# Cannot import numpy in pypy3 (installs fine with pip)

Tags: python, numpy, pypy

Been trying to install numpy on `pypy3` with `pip`. The install works fine, but when I do `import numpy`, I get the following error. Anyone have any advice?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/carl/pypy3-v6.0.0-linux64/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/home/carl/pypy3-v6.0.0-linux64/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "/home/carl/pypy3-v6.0.0-linux64/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 44, in <module>
    arange.__module__ = 'numpy'
AttributeError: readonly attribute '__module__'
```

Using the latest `pypy3` versions from the site on Ubuntu

```
Python 3.5.3 (fdd60ed87e94, Apr 24 2018, 06:10:04)
[PyPy 6.0.0 with GCC 6.2.0 20160901] on linux
```

Latest `pip` too

```
pip 18.1 from /home/carl/pypy3-v6.0.0-linux64/site-packages/pip (python 3.5)
```

Comment: have you tried with `pip3`?

Comment: Yes I should've been more clear, i'm referring to pip3 for pypy3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`numpy` 1.16.0 is incompatible with `pypy3` v6.0, more details [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/12740). The solution is to use either `numpy` 1.15.4, or to use a `pypy3` nightly while waiting for the next release.